# .NET core web application Angular doesnt work

Tags: angular, web, .net-core

[image]
I am trying to start a sammple application but doesnt work.

I get errors like
ng is not recognized as an internal or external command - i run npm install

-g @angular/cli
then i get Couldn't read dependencies ENOENT, open '...\package.json'

after Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics

and always some very strange errors.

What i am doing wrong? What should do to install it from beggining and just run demo web application from visual studio.
Can someone provide me a demo step by step to run this web app?

Comment: What version of Angular you are trying to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have installed all the dependencies in order to initiate Angular application as angular package is hosted on npm library.

Please follow the steps given in Angular quick start page -
https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @Gunjan Khanwilkar

If you are looking to start an `ASP.NET Core project` which supports including Angular 2+ you need to choose

```
ASP.NET Core Web Application
```

More details about how to use ASP.NET Core with Angular you can find in this article as well as many other articles on the internet, they show it step by step.
https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/10/19/angular2-aspnet-core-mvc/